# Can I push a modal view controller from within another modal view controller?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I've got a rootViewController that, at one point, displays a peoplePickerNavigationController. I'm trying to push a second view controller when my user selects a specific contact property, like so:

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)picker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABPersonRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
RuleBuilder *ruleBuilder = [[RuleBuilder alloc] initWithNibName:@"RuleBuilder" bundle:nil];
[self pushModalViewController:ruleBuilder animated:YES];
[ruleBuilder release];
return NO;
}
```

This compiles just fine, but when I run the code in the simulator and run through the peoplePicker, nothing happens when I select a contact property. On a whim, I added a [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; just before [ruleBuilder release]; and that dismisses the peoplePicker, but otherwise has no effect on my missing ruleBuilder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
[picker pushModalViewController:ruleBuilder animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work if the screen you're on doesn't have a navigation controller.  PresentModalViewController doesn't do it; it only shows one.

Comment: Oscar is right so this should not be considered the right answer until it is updated.

Comment: If the screen you are on doesn't have a nav controller, create one with **ruleBuilder** as its root controller.  Then present the NavConttroller.